# variables not carried over from this script

Tags: batch-file, video, batch-processing, batch-rename

this script takes a video file as input and after preliminary renaming extrapolates values such as `title` and `year` or `episode` along with a search strings `strict` for finding duplicate videos and `loose` for finding all episodes of a series. it then does a controlled filebot rename for the file.

```
set "filename=%~n1"
set "parentdir=%~2"

:: =============================================================================================================================
::      1. FILENAME VALIDATOR
:: =============================================================================================================================

set "original=%filename%"
set "filename=%filename:!=%"
set "filename=%filename:&=and%"

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "filename=!filename:%%=_percent!"
    for /l %%s in (0,1,9) do set "filename=!filename:series.%%s=S0%%s!"
    for /l %%e in (0,1,9) do set "filename=!filename:%%eof2=E0%%e!"
    for /l %%e in (0,1,9) do set "filename=!filename:%%eof3=E0%%e!"
    for /l %%e in (0,1,9) do set "filename=!filename:%%eof4=E0%%e!"
    for /l %%e in (0,1,9) do set "filename=!filename:%%eof5=E0%%e!"
    for /l %%e in (0,1,9) do set "filename=!filename:%%eof6=E0%%e!"
    for /l %%e in (0,1,9) do set "filename=!filename:%%eof7=E0%%e!"
    for /l %%e in (0,1,9) do set "filename=!filename:%%eof8=E0%%e!"
    for /l %%e in (0,1,9) do set "filename=!filename:%%eof9=E0%%e!"
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion

if not "%filename%"=="%original%" ren "%~1" "%filename%%~x1" && echo validated "%original%"

:: =============================================================================================================================
::      2. EXTRAS RENAMER
:: =============================================================================================================================

echo "%~p1" | find /i "extras" >nul || goto skip_extras
echo "%~p1" | find /i "featurettes" >nul || goto skip_extras

if not defined parentdir echo detected featurette but parentdir was not delivered && exit /b
call :extrapolate "%parentdir%"
ren "%filename%%~x1" "%name% extras - %filename%%~x1" && echo renamed extra "%name% extras - %filename%%~x1" && exit /b
:skip_extras

:: =============================================================================================================================
::      3. EXTRAPOLATOR
:: =============================================================================================================================

:extrapolate
set "type=" & set "year=" & set "ss=" & set "ep=" & set "episode="
set "name=%filename%"
echo "%name%"| find " " >nul || set "name=%name:.= %" & rem if no spaces then then safer to replace dots

:: episode number: last tag first

SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /L %%e IN (100,1,199) DO (
 SET "modname=!name:E%%e=!"
 IF "!modname!" neq "%name%" (
  SET "setcmd=set name=!name:E%%e=& set ep=E%%e& set type=show& rem !"
  GOTO gotep
 )
)
FOR /L %%e IN (10,1,99) DO (
 SET "modname=!name:E%%e=!"
 IF "!modname!" neq "%name%" (
  SET "setcmd=set name=!name:E%%e=& set ep=E%%e& set type=show& rem !"
  GOTO gotep
 )
 SET "modname=!name:E0%%e=!"
 IF "!modname!" neq "%name%" (
  SET "setcmd=set name=!name:E0%%e=& set ep=E0%%e& set type=show& rem !"
  GOTO gotep
 )
)

FOR /L %%e IN (0,1,9) DO (
 SET "modname=!name:E0%%e=!"
 IF "!modname!" neq "%name%" (
  SET "setcmd=set name=!name:E0%%e=& set ep=E0%%e& set type=show& rem !"
  GOTO gotep
 )
 SET "modname=!name:E00%%e=!"
 IF "!modname!" neq "%name%" (
  SET "setcmd=set name=!name:E00%%e=& set ep=E00%%e& set type=show& rem !"
  GOTO gotep
 )
 SET "modname=!name:%%eof=!"
 IF "!modname!" neq "%name%" (
  SET "setcmd=set name=!name:%%eof=& set ep=E0%%e& set type=show& rem !"
  GOTO gotep
 )
 SET "modname=!name:x0%%e=!" 
 IF "!modname!" neq "%name%" (
  SET "setcmd=set name=!name:x0%%e=& set ep=E0%%e& set type=show& rem !"
  GOTO gotep
 )
)
ENDLOCAL
GOTO skipep
:gotep
%setcmd%
ENDLOCAL & SET "type=%type%" & SET "ep=%ep%" & SET name=%name% 
:skipep

:: season number: second to last tag second

SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /L %%e IN (0,1,9) DO (
 SET "modname=!name:S0%%e=!"
 IF "!modname!" neq "%name%" (
  SET "setcmd=set name=!name:S0%%e=& set ss=S0%%e& set type=show& rem !"
  GOTO gotss
 )
)
FOR /L %%e IN (10,1,99) DO (
 SET "modname=!name:S%%e=!"
 IF "!modname!" neq "%name%" (
  SET "setcmd=set name=!name:S%%e=& set ss=S%%e& set type=show& rem !"
  GOTO gotss
 )
)
FOR /L %%e IN (0,1,9) DO (
 SET "modname=!name:series.%%e=!"
 IF "!modname!" neq "%name%" (
  SET "setcmd=set name=!name:series.%%e=& set ss=S0%%e& set type=show& rem !"
  GOTO gotss
 )
)
ENDLOCAL
GOTO skipss
:gotss
%setcmd%
ENDLOCAL & SET "type=%type%" & SET "ss=%ss%" & SET name=%name%
:skipss

if defined ep if not defined ss set ss=S01
SET "episode=%ss%%ep%"

:: year number: first tag last

SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /L %%e IN (1957,1,2057) DO (
 SET "modname=!name:%%e=!"
 IF "!modname!" neq "%name%" (
  SET "setcmd=set name=!name:%%e=& set year=%%e& if not defined type set type=film& rem !"
  GOTO gotyear
 )
)
ENDLOCAL
GOTO skipyear
:gotyear
%setcmd%
ENDLOCAL & SET "year=%year%" & SET "type=%type%" & SET name=%name%
:skipyear

:: finalize

:: changes for general use
set name=%name: - = %

:: trim last useless letter from name
set "name=%name%endtrimmer"
set "name=%name:(endtrimmer=endtrimmer%"
set "name=%name:[endtrimmer=endtrimmer%"
set "name=%name: endtrimmer=endtrimmer%"
set "name=%name: endtrimmer=%"
set "name=%name:_endtrimmer=%"
set "name=%name:endtrimmer=%"

:: set strings
if "%type%"=="film" set "strict=%name: =?%?(%year%)"
if "%type%"=="show" if defined year set "strict=%name: =?%?(%year%)?%episode%"
if "%type%"=="show" if not defined year set "strict=%name: =?%?%episode%"
if "%type%"=="show" if defined year set "loose=%name: =?%?(%year%)?s"
if "%type%"=="show" if not defined year set "loose=%name: =?%?s"

SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
FOR %%a IN (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) DO SET "name=!name:%%a=%%a!"
endlocal & SET "name=%name%"

:: declare (disable never delete)
if "%type%"=="film" echo extrapolated film %strict:?= %
if "%type%"=="show" echo extrapolated episode %strict:?= %

:: =============================================================================================================================
::      4. FILEBOT MODERATOR
:: =============================================================================================================================

if not defined type exit /b

:: prep fake temp file
set tempdir=%temp%\%date:~3,2%%date:~6,2%%date:~11,2%%time:~1,1%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%%time:~9,2%
mkdir "%tempdir%" && copy /y nul "%tempdir%\%filename%.mkv" >nul

:: variables (to shorten lines)
if "%type%"=="film" set cf=--db TheMovieDb --format "{n} ({y}) {director} {genres} r{rating} {vf} {vc} {ac} {imdbid}"
if "%type%"=="show" set cf=--db TheTVDb --format "{n} {s00e00} {t} {vf} {vc} {ac} {imdbid}"

:: rename fake temp file
filebot -rename "%tempdir%\%filename%%~x1" --q "%name% %year%" %cf% >nul 2>nul

:: new name into variable
for /r "%tempdir%" %%i in (*) do set "new=%%~ni"

:: declare failure
if "%filename%"=="%new%" echo filebot refused to rename "%~n1" && exit /b

:: if what expected rename 4real
echo %%new:^&=^^^&%% | findstr /i /b /c:"%strict:?= %" >nul && goto 4real

:: if not reformat and try again
set "new=%new:'=%"
set "new=%new:,=%"
echo %%new:^&=^^^&%% | findstr /i /b /c:"%strict:?= %" >nul && goto 4real

:: declare failure and confirm override
echo "%new%" does not match "%string%"
choice /t 20 /c yn /n /d n /m "override and approve rename? [Y]es or [N]o: "
if "%errorlevel%"=="1" goto 4real
exit /b

:4real
filebot -rename "%~dp1%filename%%~x1" --q "%name% %year%" %cf% >nul 2>nul
if not exist "%filename%" echo successfully renamed "%filename%"
exit /b
```

none of the variables are carried over to the script that called for them. I can't for the life of me figure out why except it must have something to do with `endlocal` or `disabledelayedexpansion`, which look fine to me as far as I can tell.

Comment: setlocal begins a new `scope` for variables and endlocal removes this scope and restores all variables to their pervious values. You could remove all but one setlocals and remove all endlocals

Comment: I was hesitant to try this at first since a good portion of the code is not mine originally (part 3) but I got it to work now! thx!